# Measurement Protocol Google Analytics Post request not registering page views

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, measurement-protocol

I'm trying to register [source](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters?hl=en#cs) and [medium](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters?hl=en#cm) impressions using the [Google Analytics Measurement Protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1?hl=en).

I'm not seeing pageviews or source/mediums being recorded in the GA dashboard.

I'm running this snippet in my head tag.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var randomid = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
  var path = window.location.pathname;
  var pathuri = encodeURIComponent(window.location.pathname)
  var url = 'https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-XXXXXXXX-X&cid='+randomid+'&t=pageview&cs=tvstest3&cm=ctvtest3&dp='+pathuri;
  $.post(url, function(data, status){
    console.log("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });
</script>
```

Which results in a network call of

```
https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=UA-XXXXXX-X&cid=537396&t=pageview&cs=tvstest3&cm=ctvtest3&dp=%2Ftest3.html
```

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/ returns "Hit is valid!"

and if I send the request to https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect

```
Data: {
  "hitParsingResult": [ {
    "valid": true,
    "parserMessage": [ ],
    "hit": "/debug/collect?v=1\u0026tid=UA-XXXXXXX-X\u0026cid=521292\u0026t=pageview\u0026cs=tvstest3\u0026cm=ctvtest3\u0026dp=%2Ftest3.html"
  } ],
  "parserMessage": [ {
    "messageType": "INFO",
    "description": "Found 1 hit in the request."
  } ]
}

Status: success
```

Can anyone shed some light on why I'm not seeing pageviews and source/medium being recorded.

Thanks!

-cwmacken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If bot filtering in your view  is enabled  the hit may not be recorded. This is because using the Measurement protocol data protocol looks a lot like a bot injecting data into your property.

Try to disable this checkbox in your View settings:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that disabling bot filtering will cause the debug endpoint to record hits?

Comment: No, I'm not talking about endpoint debugging. His problem is that he doesn't see the hits in GA and in the first code example he doesn't send them to the debug end point (that's a test he does later).

Comment: Ok as long as we agree that bot filtering does not effect the purpose of the debugging endpoint.

Comment: @MichelePisani did this and I can see it in the realtime view. Waiting to see it propagate properly in source/medium. I'll update when I see data there.

Comment: Just saw it pop up in source/medium. Thanks for the help @MichelePisani I would have never found that.

Answer (score 0):

## debugging endpoint vs collection endpoint

The [Debug endpoint](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/validating-hits?hl=en) is just for Validating Hits

> https://www.google-analytics.com/debug/collect

> This document describes how to validate Google Analytics Measurement Protocol hits.

The debug endpoint doesn't actually send the hit to google analytics.  If you want the data registered in google analytics you should send it to

> https://www.google-analytics.com/collect

Once you have changed the endpoint you should then, check the real time reports to ensure that the hit was received. If not ensure that bot filtering has been disabled on the account.

The wait between 24 - 48 hours to see the data in the standard reports, due to processing latency.

## Post data in body

Beyond the data should be sent in the body of your request as post data.

```
POST /collect HTTP/1.1
Host: www.google-analytics.com

v=1&tid=UA-XXXXXXXX-X&cid='+randomid+'&t=pageview&cs=tvstest3&cm=ctvtest3&dp='+pathuri
```

## Code

I am not a JavaScript dev but i think you should be looking at something like this.

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'https://www.google-analytics.com/collect';
var params = 'v=1&tid=UA-XXXXXXXX-X&cid='+randomid+'&t=pageview&cs=tvstest3&cm=ctvtest3&dp='+pathuri';
http.open('POST', url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send(params);
```

Comment: @DalmTo Michele is correct I was only sending info to the debugging endpoint to test if my call was working correctly. Thank you for the answer though. Appreciated.